# Rails delete row when date field is past time.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have columns in my database table called `eventdate` and `eventtime`.

Let's say the event date is 01/02/2016 and the time is 19:00. (GMT)

I want to have it so that the event is removed as soon as it reaches 7pm on the 1st of Feb, 2016 (Bearing in mind this table has a lot of events inside it.)

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Run a cron job or use `whenever` to check for expired events. Another option is to automatically schedule event deletion using some form of long-term event processing. How many is "a lot"? That matters.

Comment: @DaveNewton Hey, I've got scheduler running on heroku already, it currently varys day by day, One day could only have 3 events to remove another day might have 100

Comment: Not asking how many events you have to remove, rather how many events are there altogether. In any case, simply having an index on that table may be enough--depends partially on how granular you need the deletion to be. If it has to be "exact" then you'll need something other than a full table scan.

Comment: @DaveNewton It has around 15kish rows, And thats constantly being added to

Comment: And presumably deleted from? In any case, the "best" answer still is kind of "it depends", particularly about how important it is to physically delete them as hinted to by Michal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) Add a scope to events called :expired that returns any events that meet the criteria you described. Write tests for the scope.

2) Add a service object whose job it is to delete expired events. Don't forget your tests.

3) Add and install the whenever gem. Edit config/schedule.rb to run the service object at a particular interval.

4) Deploy.

Comment: anychance you could dumb this down a little? I am so confused

Comment: I can't really elaborate without knowing more about your problem. It sounds like you are trying to delete expired events from a table. Is that correct? Also, what datatype are you using for eventtime? In thinking about the query a bit, I can't picture how you're able to sort or query on time. There is no "time" datatype. If you're using datetime it would make more sense to combine the two columns into a single event_date_and_time column (or whatever you want to call it).

Answer (score 2):

For starters I'm not sure why do you keep separate field for date and time instead of just one field. That would make SQL queries much faster I believe.

Secondly, as I understand you care about a row being "invisible" after event date time so what I would do is query the table with scope `where('event_datetime > ?', Time.now)` so you don't have to worry about removing the rows right away. 
Then, as you already did, move row removing to background and no matter how long does it take, your rows are "invisible" anyway.